# Python keeps on stating that 'withdrawal' amount is always over 'accountbalance1.balance1' amount

Tags: python

When attempting to withdraw money from 'balance1' and into 'balance2', Python keeps on telling me that 'withdrawal' input is always more than 'accountbalance1.balance1' (lack of better term since it's almost 2:00 AM and I currently do not have the creative juices to think of a more apt name).

```
class Account():
    def __init__(self, name1 = "", name2 = "", balance1 = 0, balance2 = 0):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.name2 = name2
        self.balance1 = balance1
        self.balance2 = balance2

    def name(self):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.name2 = name2

    def balance(self):
        self.balance1 = balance1
        self.balance2 = balance2

print()
name_1 = input("What is Owner 1's name? ")
balance_1 = input("What is Owner 1's current balance? ")
name_2 = input("What is Owner 2's name? ")
balance_2 = 0
print()

accountname1 = Account(name1 = name_1)
accountbalance1 = Account(balance1 = balance_1)
accountname2 = Account(name2 = name_2)
accountbalance2 = Account(balance2 = balance_2)

print("Owner 1's name: " + accountname1.name1)
print("Owner 1's current balance: $" + str(accountbalance1.balance1))
print()
print("Owner 2's name: " + accountname2.name2)
print("Owner 2's current balance: $" + str(accountbalance2.balance2))

for x in range (0,2):
    print()
    withdrawal = input("Select the amount you would like to withdraw from Owner 1's Account: ")
    if withdrawal > accountbalance1.balance1:
        print()
        print("Unfortunately, that amount is more than the amount currently within Owner 1's account. Please try again.")
    else:
        accountbalance.balance1 = accountbalance1.balance1 - withdrawal
        accountbalance.balance2 = accountbalance2.balance2 + withdrawal

print()
print("Owner 1's name: " + accountname1.name1)
print("Owner 1's current balance: $" + str(accountbalance1.balance1))
print()
print("Owner 2's name: " + accountname2.name2)
print("Owner 2's current balance: $" + str(accountbalance2.balance2))
```

Specifically, this part (taken from above):

```
for x in range (0,2):
    print()
    withdrawal = input("Select the amount you would like to withdraw from Owner 1's Account: ")
    if withdrawal > accountbalance1.balance1:
        print()
        print("Unfortunately, that amount is more than the amount currently within Owner 1's account. Please try again.")
    else:
        accountbalance.balance1 = accountbalance1.balance1 - withdrawal
        accountbalance.balance2 = accountbalance2.balance2 + withdrawal
```

What can I do in order to rectify the mistake and have Python correctly check of the withdrawal amount is greater or less than the balance1 amount?

Comment: `input()` always return a string and not an integer, which it seems like you are dealing with here. If you want to convert the input, wrap it like so: `int(input())`, but keep in mind, that if you enter something not parsable to an integer, it will throw an error.

Comment: `input` returns a string, so you are comparing strings, not numbers.  Use `int(input(...))` or `float(input(...))` to convert.